# JQuery - click function on working on first 6 classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm using a flipbook library to make a catalog for cordova(ios) and am attempting to add a zoom feature to individual pages.

For some reason, the zoom only works on the first 6 pages/classes it comes too.

the following fiddle doesn't contain the images and seems to have issues with the remTemp function, but I assure you it works in the browser and on ios.

http://jsfiddle.net/vAVdZ/

HTML:

```
 <div id="zoomer"></div> 
   <div id="zoom-viewport">
    <div id="flipbook">

<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/cover.jpg"  class="small i1"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/inner-cover.jpg"  class="small i0"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/1.jpg"  class="small i1"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/2.jpg"  class="small i2"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/3.jpg"  class="small i3"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/4.jpg"  class="small i4"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/5.jpg"  class="small i5"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/6.jpg"  class="small i6"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/7.jpg"  class="small i7"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/8.jpg"  class="small i8"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/9.jpg"  class="small i9"></div>
<div class="flippage"><img src="pages/10.jpg"  class="small i10"></div>
</div></div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.small').click(function() { 

    cls = $(this).attr("class");
    rem = 'small i';
    clas = cls.replace(rem,'');

    imagesrc = $(this).attr("src");

    if (clas % 2 == 0) {
    loc = "left";
    $('body').append("<img src='"+imagesrc+"' id='temp' onclick='remTemp();'class='temp small' style='position:absolute; left:12px; top:199px; z-index:5 !important;'>");

    }
    if (clas % 2 != 0) {
    loc = "right"
    $('body').append("<img src='"+imagesrc+"' id='temp' onclick='remTemp();'class='temp small' style='position:absolute; left:512px; top:199px; z-index:5 !important;'>");
    }




    $(this).css('z-index','-1');
    $('.temp').animate({ 
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    width:1000,
    height: 707
    }, 1000
    );



    });

    function remTemp() {
    $('img').remove('#temp');
    }
```

I have absolutely no idea why the click function stops after 6 pages, i've tried removing the first x pages and it just does 6 no matter where i try it from (94 pages total)

Thanks

*just as a note, i've tried using many different selectors and still having the same issue.

Comment: post a link to the live site If you can.

Comment: first of all use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()` and check once..

Comment: unfortunately it isn't a live site, it's an ipad app using ios safari engine. good call about moving to prop.

Comment: Do **all** of the pages exist on the page at page load, or are some dynamically added?

Comment: Did you check the size of `$('.small')`? Are you sure it contains all the `img.small`? Maybe you can try event delegation instead of event binding on specified elements.

Comment: i haven't no, but I have also tried using '.flipbook img' as the selector etc. I'm unsure how to action your suggestion.

Comment: It appears they do not, all appear at page load. however, phonegap is not working properly with .live or .bind

Comment: I've had to do this the dirty way and wrote some PHP to create a separate function for each and every page.